# Functionality Similar to Perl's AUTOLOAD in C++

Tags: c++, autoload, generic-programming

Perl allows you to catch a call to undefined method using a feature called `AUTOLOAD`. Whenever you call a method that Perl cannot find, it will look for an `AUTOLOAD` method and call that instead. This can be used in many different ways.
For more information see: [AUTOLOAD](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#AUTOLOAD)

Recently I've gotten into C++, and was curious if there was a way to emulate this kind of functionality in a C++ program. I know everything in C++ needs to be pretty much defined at compile time which makes this a tricky problem, but I imagine there has to be some technique involving templates or some other trickery that can at least come close.

What is the closest you can get to Perl's `AUTOLOAD` functionality in C++?

Comment: Are you aware that the copy of the Perl documentation you linked to is ancient? perl 5.00503 was released in 1999. Slightly more up to date: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#AUTOLOAD

Comment: > And don't just say it's impossible! Because then you'd be lying. Perl was implemented using C. And I can imagine this would be a much more difficult task for C! ;)


This kind reasoning is false ! Due to the fact that perl dynamicly typed and interpreted there are thing you can do in perl but can't in C (and C++ which are staticly typed and compiled)

Comment: Thanks @melpomene, I've updated my link to the newer documentation.

Comment: @nefas, Technically implementing a whole new dynamically typed language using C++ would be one way to do it :) ...although not the answer I would be looking for lol

Comment: There may be way to do this by "hacking" the vtable (or making a compiler extension but I assume that's not the answer you are looking for) but if it is possible I'm pretty sure that it's an ugly hack.

Comment: The *standard* C++ language has no facilities for this.  You would need to modify the compiler with the same C code that Perl has.  Another alternative is to implement the functionality in your program.  Place your functions into dynamic libraries, then search them.  You could make a table of function name vs. dynamic library to make the search faster.

Comment: C++ templates are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @tjwrona1992: *"Whenever you call an undefined method on an object, if $AUTOLOAD is defined, Perl will look for an AUTOLOAD method and call that instead. "* That's wrong. You shouldn't set `$AUTOLOAD` yourself. Perl searches for an `AUTOLOAD` subroutine *whenever* it can't find one with a matching name. `$AUTOLOAD` is set to inform `sub AUTOLOAD` what name was originally called.

Comment: What you ask requires [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(computer_programming)), something C++ doesn't provide. To achieve what you want, you'd have to reinvent a whole new type system, and that's just for starters!

Comment: If all you want is to call a thing called `AUTOLOAD`, if it exists and there is no exact binding, then an appropriate linker can easily do that. Nothing fancy in the language is necessary.

Comment: Read about [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) & [dlsym(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html) & [C++ dlopen minihowto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/). It could inspire you. But C++ is separating compile time from run time.

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible within a meaningful definition of Perl's `AUTOLOAD`.

The basic problem is that method names are resolved at compile time in C++.  It's true that [in some cases a method *call* is resolved at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039031/which-function-calls-are-not-resolved-at-compile-time-in-object-oriented-program).  But then it is a decision about *which* already-defined method to call.

The basic functionality of having a method name that is called in your source file, and compiling your code without any method of that name existing, does not exist in C++.

Of course if you think that just rewriting Perl is a legitimate answer, then the answer is yes, it's possible. But then it becomes a trivial question.

Comment: Just sayin' ...

Comment: @dan1111: It's your answer of course, but your changes are wrong. Nothing "springs into existence" in Perl either. `AUTOLOAD` is just an error handler, and if you want a new subroutine to be created then you have to write extremely fancy code in that error handler to create the code for a new subroutine, compile it, and insert it into the appropriate package symbol table. The language with the nearest behaviour that I know is [Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/lua/info)

Comment: @dan1111: *"then having anything that is undefined handled by a default function at run time"* This is why I made my original edit. `AUTOLOAD` must have been compiled during any one of many compile phases before the run time can find it. There is no compile/run pair in Perl; there are multiple phases of both, even within every `use` statement, and it's impossible to say anything more than I wrote in my edit and also get it right without useless complexity.

Comment: @Borodin, changing your edit was accidental; I thought I was editing a precious version of my own text at the time.

Comment: @dan1111: It's fine: it's your answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Come on guys... Stop being so pessimistic and just saying things are impossible because it's the easy thing to do.  There's always a way to do anything in every language.  Yes sometimes it is super hacky and horrible, but super hacky horrible answers are perfectly fine here!  I want to figure this out as a learning experience, not to put it in production code.

This is by no means a good, or complete answer, but this is the closest I could get from C++.  In my example the `call` method is being used as a sort of hacky "autoloader." It can definitely be done better and there are definitely ways to get closer to Perl's `AUTOLOAD` functionality without writing a whole new language.  All I'm asking is for you to get creative!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    Test() {
            table["get"]["x"] = 1;
            table["get"]["y"] = 2;
    }

    int call(string method, string arg) {
        if (method == "get") {
            return table[method][arg];
        }
        else {
            // Do something else
        }
        return 0;
    }
private:
    map<string, map<string, int> > table;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Test test;
    cout << test.call("get","x") << endl;
    cout << test.call("get","y") << endl;
}
```